# Why is my header component rerendering when no new props are coming...?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

https://codesandbox.io/s/crimson-field-83hx6

I have a Header component that returns a fixed text with a `console.log`

```
const Header = props => {
  console.log("header render");
  return (
    <header>
      <h1>header</h1>
    </header>
  );
};
```

Within my parent component, I have a function called `changeTab` that changes the tab and sets it into the state:

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    tabs: {
      selectedTab: ""
    }
  };

  changeTab(name) {
    let tabs = { ...this.state.tabs };
    tabs.selectedTab = name;

    this.setState({ tabs });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header />
        <button onClick={() => this.changeTab()}>change tab</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

When I click on the button to change the tab, the `console.log` from the header fires. Why is this happening? No new props are being passed to Header and also Header isnt reliant on state.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. You can use [on-site interactive stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/338537/1218980) to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Didnt think this really needed an example because its a pretty basic react question but ok. I added it. Header gets re rendered when button is clicked. @EmileBergeron

Comment: And your changeTab is inside your 'parent component'?

Comment: Yup, I added a codesandbox that replicates it.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why your `Header` component is being rendered again after running the `changeTab` function is because you're calling the `setState` function of a `React.Component`. This function runs a re-render of the component it's calling on and all its children.

A quote from the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate):

> setState() enqueues changes to the component state and tells React that this component and its children need to be re-rendered with the updated state. This is the primary method you use to update the user interface in response to event handlers and server responses.

Your `Header` component has nothing to do with the state of the parent component. But it's re-rendered because it's the child of the parent component.

If you don't want your Header component to be re-rendered upon clicking the changeTab function, you should consider to move the logic of your tabs to a different component, or moving the Header component up the dom-tree (if possible).

Comment: ...Is this actually the answer? It doesnt make sense for your whole project to re render if one small part of the state changes. What would be the right way to handle this then? How do i prevent my whole web app from re rendering when only 1 small value changes?

Comment: My project originally had Redux but I decided it was overkill to use Redux. I didn't have these issues with useless re-renders when my app was still on Redux.

Comment: Only children rerender. That's why it's important to consider which component holds your application state. Redux has components connect directly to state, but I believe will still cause child components of connected components to rerender.

Comment: Yes this is how React works. Children will be re-rendered if the state or props of a component is changed. Internally they are needed to keep everything up to date. Maybe you could read the Reconciliation topic in the React documentation if you'd like to know more about the algorithm behind it. @CalIrvine yes children of connected Redux component will be re-rendered too on new props. 
Re-rendering of children always happens when there's a new state or new props. Unless you're using lifecycles to block a re-render of the parent